# C# Change backgroundcolor specific row

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I've created a new project from the Grid App (XAML) template (C# Windows Store).
So far I've changed nothing in the template, but I would like to change the backgroundcolor from a specific row in the grid.

```
<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I would like to change the backgroundcolor from row 0 (which contains the page title).
Any ideas?? Thanks in advance!

This row consits of:

```
    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't set the background color on the Grid.Row itself, instead set the Background property on whatever occupies this row.

For example

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid Background="Red" Grid.Row="0">
    <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

EDIT:
Updated for Silverlight; TextBlock doesn't have Background so you have to put the control in another Border or grid container which does have background. Code updated to reflect this.

Comment: unfortunately a textblock item does not contain of a background property. I've edited my post to show which items are in that row.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I didn't see the silverlight tag on your post, the WPF TextBlock has Background.

Comment: But I don't want to change the background of just the button, it has to be the entire row.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly, you have to wrap your controls in a Border or Grid (something which does have a Background property)

Comment: <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#26111D"></Grid>
Did the trick, thank you!

Comment: Just wondering if I could do it in the StandardStyles.xaml file so I don't have to edit each page. In all my pages I call the StaticResource LayoutRootStyle.

    <Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDDF2AE" />
        <Setter Property="ChildrenTransitions">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <EntranceThemeTransition/>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

I've allready set a background property for the entire body.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, what happens if you create a style to set the Background with a TargetType="Grid" ?

Answer (score 2):

How about inserting border where you need it

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></Border>
    <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
    <Border Background="blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"></Border>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Test2</TextBlock>
 </Grid>
```

note that you can especify the columns span in case of include more columns