# Changing background color of some rows in a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bound combobox and depending on the values I get back in the records I want to change the background color of certain rows in the combobox. Is this possible and if so how?

A little more clarification. I'm looking at one of the fields in each row and based on its value I want to change the background color. So I could be changing all of the row, some of the rows, or none of the rows.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Well nothing as I've only found ways to change all the background colors or the selected item background color. I haven't seen an example of changing of changing the background color of certain rows.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

Cheers, Martin

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356273/c-sharp-change-backgroundcolor-specific-row

Comment: I don't see how that would work for what I want to do with the combobox. I'll have X number of records and for each of those records I want to look at the field Y in that row. If Y is false then set the background to a certain color otherwise keep it the default color.

Comment: So you want to set the background based on a cell value?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381726/datagrid-row-background-based-on-cell-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `ItemContainerStyle` to set the item background color per-row.  You can bind to a property in the row's data context, and use an `IValueConverter` to get the appropriate brush. Eg, assuming that the items have a property "Y":

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <local:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="BoolToBrushConverter" />
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" 
                    Value="{Binding Y,Converter={StaticResource BoolToBrushConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Then the "BoolToBrushConverter" would be something like this:

```
public class BoolToBrushConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as bool? == true) ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Going to accept this answer, but I had to make one change to the converter to make it work:   
   
return (value as bool? == true) ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);

Answer (score 1):

Create a template for item which includes a text block bound to your display value.

Create a custom IValueConverter that converts your other value to a colour.

Bind the background to your other value and use the converter.

Answer (score 0):

[Combobox with border seperators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otjCG.png)

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```